# How can I divide $(x^2+1)^{86}$ by $x^2-x+1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

I have $(x^2+1)^{86}$ and $x^2-x+1$.

Need to divide $(x^2+1)^{86}$ by $x^2-x+1$.

How can I do this? I just don't know where to begin.

Comment: $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{ac}{bc}$. As you realise very well, it's enormously difficult to divide by a three-term expression. So, the question is: what does $c$ need to be in order to turn your three-term expression into a two-term expression?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

So your problem is $(x^{2} + 1)^{86} \mod{(x^{2} - x + 1)}$. That is considering $x^{2} = x - 1 \implies x^{3} = x^{2} - x = -1$. Now $(x^{2} + 1) \equiv x \mod{(x^{2} - x + 1)} \implies (x^{2} + 1)^{86} \equiv x^{86} \mod{(x^{2} - x + 1)} 
\\\equiv (x^{3})^{28}x^{2} \mod{(x^{2} - x + 1)}
\\ \equiv x^{2} \mod{(x^{2} - x + 1)} 
\\\equiv x-1\mod{(x^{2} - x + 1)}$

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with complex numbers, you can solve this problem this way.

Let $\varepsilon$ be a root of the quadratic equation $x^2-x+1=0$ and
$$
(x^2+1)^{86}=(x^2-x+1)q(x)+ax+b.\tag1
$$
Since $\varepsilon^6=1$ (why?) and $\varepsilon=1+\varepsilon^2$, it follows from $(1)$ that
$$
(\varepsilon^2+1)^{86}=a\varepsilon+b\Rightarrow \varepsilon^{86}=a\varepsilon+b\Rightarrow\varepsilon^2=a\varepsilon+b\Rightarrow a=1, b=-1.
$$

Comment: What is $q(x)$ then?

Comment: @ТymaGaidash, I'm sure the OP knows the answer to this question.

Comment: $\varepsilon^6=1$ because it's one of the cube roots of $-1$...